# add action only on post publish - not update

Tags: posts, actions, publish

I have action which adds meta field with value on post publish. Problem is that when I update post meta field is reset to default value.

I already tried 'new_to_publish' instead of 'publish_post' but it doesn't work.

```
add_action('publish_post', 'add_custom_field_automatically');
function add_custom_field_automatically($post_ID) {
  global $wpdb;

  if(!wp_is_post_revision($post_ID)) {
    update_post_meta($post_ID, 'votes_count', '0');

}
}
```

Still can't make it work

```
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'wpse120996_post_status_publish', 10, 3 );
function wpse120996_post_status_publish( $new_status, $old_status, $post_ID ) { 
    if ( $new_status == 'publish' && $old_status == 'pending' ) {
          global $wpdb;

  if(!wp_is_post_revision($post_ID)) {
    update_post_meta($post_ID, 'votes_count', '0');
    }
}}
```

As I can understand it - every time status changes from pending to publish do whatever is inside if. But it doesn't work.

In my site I have post rating system with meta field 'votes_count' where are stored votes. When I query votes_count from highest to lowest it doesn't show posts with no votes, so I need to populate it with default value 0 to include them into query. Everything works fine but when i update votes are reset to 0... Posts are published by users with pending status which I check and publish.

Comment: Some counter questions: 1. Are you sure if you got your post statuses right? 2. I know - from yesterdays question - this is about the rating system you implemented - is the only thing you are trying to make sure that there is a value returned or echoed?

Comment: why not just use your first example but check if the meta data already exists first and only add it if it doesn't?

Comment: I query post by votes_count with meta_key="votes_count" and meta_value="meta_value_num" and today I realized that queries don't show posts with no votes. I checked database and there meta fields named votes_count have only posts with 1 or more votes. So I came into conclusion that meta fields are created when user votes and next step in my thinking was to auto create meta field votes_count with value 0 for every new post. That Im trying to make with this function. I tried to edit code from yesterday but with no luck.

Comment: @milo you're absolutely right

Comment: I didnt answer questions. 1. Im pretty sure with statuses - when user creates post its "pending" and I publish it after checking 2. I think I already answered it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like @milo pointed out in the comment, checking if the post meta exists is the easiest way to achieve what you want - like this:

```
add_action('publish_post', 'wpse120996_add_custom_field_automatically');
function wpse120996_add_custom_field_automatically($post_id) {
    global $wpdb;
    $votes_count = get_post_meta($post_id, 'votes_count', true);
    if( empty( $votes_count ) && ! wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) {
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'votes_count', '0');
    }
}
```

---

**→ On creation/publish not on updates**

I'm keeping this, because it fits the matter of doing things *on publish and not on update*. **But** `auto-draft` → `publish` only works on first publishing a post and only if a post gets published directly. There might be the need to cover more cases, for example `draft` → `publish` or `pending` → `publish`.

You could try:

```
//it's specific because you specify the hook like this {$old_status}_to_{$new_status}
add_action( 'auto-draft_to_publish', 'wpse120996_specific_post_status_transition' );
function wpse120996_specific_post_status_transition() { 
        //your code
}
```

instead of using `new_to_publish`.

→ Take a look at [Post Status Transitions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions) for additional information.

Or you could work with the generic hook `transition_post_status` like this:

```
//it's generic because you specify post statuses inside the function not via the hook
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'wpse120996_generic_post_status_transition', 10, 3 );
function wpse120996_generic_post_status_transition( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) { 
    if ( $new_status == 'publish' && $old_status == 'auto-draft' ) {
        //your code
    }
}
```

Another neat method doing things *on publish or to be exact first **creation** and not on updates* would be going like shown below. I opted for using the `save_post` hook, but this could be done with the `publish_post` hook too.

```
add_action('save_post', 'wpse120996_on_creation_not_update');
function wpse120996_on_creation_not_update($post_id) {
    //get_post( $post_id ) == null checks if the post is not yet in the database
    if( get_post( $post_id ) == null ) {
        //your code
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for help. I thought about such conditional earlier but it was not logical for my that empty or '' equals not exist. I thought that meta field with '' (or empty as you wrote the code) exists but has no value.

Answer (score 3):

This should work best:

```
add_action( 'publish_post' , 'my_func' , 10 , 2 );
function my_func( $ID , $post )
{
  if ( $post->post_date != $post->post_modified )
  {
    //THIS IS AN UPDATE
  }
  else
  {
    //POST JUST GOT PUBLISHED
  }
}
```

Comment: this does not work the first time a post has been updated, after the initial publish.

Answer (score 1):

Suprisingly it works. Maybe I'm not as stupid as I thought. Thank you both for help.

```
add_action('publish_post', 'add_custom_field_automatically');
function add_custom_field_automatically($post_ID) {

global $wpdb;

$meta_count = get_post_meta($post_ID, "votes_count", true);
if($meta_count == '') {
if(!wp_is_post_revision($post_ID)) {
    update_post_meta($post_ID, 'votes_count', '0');

}
}

}
```