# show the most recent date of all posts to display on front end

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, wp-query

Is there any way to show the date that the last post (most recent) from my custom post type was created?

I want to have my site show the last time a list of products was updated and i figured that it could be based on when the last post was created, or modified. is this possible?

Comment: If you don't like the question, why not explain why so the OP can learn for next time?

Comment: why the downvote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on what you're asking and what I am understanding there is [`the_modified_date()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_modified_date) or if you just want the value [`get_the_modified_date()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_modified_date).

If you ever want the creation date you could use `post_date` and `post_date_gmt`.  Several questions on this:

- [How to get post creation date?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/177065/how-to-get-post-creation-date)
- [What is considered the post's creation date for wp_insert_post?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/134512/what-is-considered-the-posts-creation-date-for-wp-insert-post)

If you are asking for a complete solution I would encourage you to search under custom post type and `wp_query`.  We have several questions that are on the topic.  If can make an edit with code I do not mind trying to help you further.

Answer (score 1):

You need a custom query for that. Basically, just a query that pulls 1 result from the posts table where the post type is your custom post type:

```
global $wpdb;

// the name you gave to your custom post type
$post_type = 'my_custom_post_type';

// this is the query string that we'll use with the $wpdb class
// selecting from the posts table where the post_type is your custom post type
// ordered DESC and LIMITed to 1 to get on the most recent entry
$query_str = "SELECT * from " . $wpdb -> prefix . "posts WHERE post_type = %s ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 1";

// it's good practice to $wpdb -> prepare queries to the database
$results = $wpdb -> get_results( $wpdb -> prepare( $query_str, $post_type ) );
```

I've used `get_results` so you have your choice of which date (created or modified) you want to use

Comment: this works too!  thanks.  i went with the wp-query only because i'm more familiar with it, but i tried this and it seems to do the same process in a different manner.