# Send a review notification email to admin when a post is 12 months old

Tags: posts, email, notifications, automation, review

I'd like to send an automated review email to the site admin whenever a post has been published for more than 12 months.

I've tried using the following code but can't seem to get it to work, or perhaps it's that I'm not entirely sure where I would put it or how I would call it???

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
//send review email to admin
function post_review_notification() {
    $old_post = 60*60*24*365;
    $site_title = get_bloginfo( 'name' );
    $to = get_option('admin_email');
    $subject = .$site_title .'- Please review' .$post->post_title;
    $message = 'This post is over 12 months old, please update or retire '."\n".'Post Title: ' .$post->post_title. "\n"."Visit the post: " . get_permalink( $post->ID );
    
   if((date('U')-get_the_time('U')) > $old_post) {
        wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message );
      }
      else {
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You ask a good question, *where I would put it or how I would call it?* I don't think you want to loop over all the posts everytime somebody visiting your site checking if any of them are more than one year old. Here is some thoughts about how this could be realized.

Assume you have a function to send a reminder about a post:

```php
function send_reminder( $post_id ) {
    if ( get_post_status( $post_id ) == 'publish' ) {
        $post_data = get_post( $post_id );
        // send a reminder about the post
    }
}
```

You can use a [`wp_schedule_single_event`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_schedule_single_event/) function of [WP Cron](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/) to schedule notification in a year when a new post gets published:

```
add_action('publish_post', 'add_reminder');
function add_reminder( $post_id ) {
    wp_schedule_single_event( time() + 60*60*24*365, 'send_reminder', array( $post_id ) );
}
```

However this action would run every time when a post gets any update. I don't know what is the best approach, read [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120996/add-action-only-on-post-publish-not-update) Q/A for more information. Maybe using a [`transition_post_status`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/transition_post_status/) hook would be better.

And now you need to add such a scheduled action to every post already published on your site. You need to use custom `WP_Query` loop over all the published posts and add a scheduled event for every one of them. This operation should be done only once, all new posts would have a reminder added via `add_reminder` function. The best approach I could think of is to do all of this as a plugin and put this loop inside a function that would be triggered on a [plugin activation](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-basics/activation-deactivation-hooks/).

Comment: Thanks for the advice Ivan, and for pointing me toward some helpful resources. I'll give this a go and see if I can get it to work.